NestJS kafka consumer topic name undefined
I'm coming back to NestJS after little while and I'm trying to set up a simple Kafka consumer. Here is a basic example of my controller using the EventPattern decorator to subscribe to a Kafka topic.
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EventPattern, Payload } from '@nestjs/microservices';

@Controller()
export class MyController {
  @EventPattern('my-topic')
  async handleMessage(@Payload() data: Record<string, unknown>) {
    console.log(data);
  }
}


This setup used to work for me in the past, but I'm now running into some issues. On startup, KafkaJS raises the following error:
KafkaJSNonRetriableError: Invalid topic undefined

It looks to me like the topic name is not being picked up properly. I'm a bit at a loss why this would be the case. For context, here is how I set up the Kafka client in main.ts:
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
...
app.connectMicroservice({
  transport: Transport.KAFKA,
  options: {
    client: {
      brokers: [process.env['KAFKA_BROKER']],
      clientId: process.env['KAFKA_CLIENT_ID'],
    },
    consumer: {
      groupId: process.env['KAFKA_CONSUMER_GROUP_ID'],
      allowAutoTopicCreation: true,
    },
  },
});
...
await app.startAllMicroservices();

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

I solved this problem by updating kafkajs to version 2.2.4
